# Array not passing from Javascript to MVC

Tags: javascript, arrays, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to pass an array from javascript back into my MVC app.  There is a `console.log(selected)` in the javascript and it outputs an array of data:

```
["<img src="https://owlexpress.kennesaw.edu/stugifs/open.gif">", "MATH 1190/01 - Calculus I", "84528", "       4.000", "Full Term", "40", "34", "6", "0", "0", "0", "Kennesaw Campus", "Classroom - 100%", "Mathematics &amp; StatisticsRoom 108", "8:00 am - 9:10 amLecture", "Aug 17, 2015", "Dec 14, 2015", "Xiaohui Rebecca  Shi (P)", ""]
```

But when the breakpoint in the controller hits I see that `selectedClassesArray == null`

Javascript:

```
$('#WatchButton').on('click', function (e) {
    var selected = [];
    $("tr.selected").each(function () {
        $(this).find('td').each(function(){
            selected.push($(this).html());                
        });
    });
    console.log(selected);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/ClassSearch/watchClasses",
        // I have tried setting data both ways with the same result:
        //data: { selectedClassesArray: selected },
        data: [selected],
        traditional: true,
        success: function (data) { alert("SUCCESS"); }
    });
});
```

ViewModel:

```
public class SelectedClassesArray
{
    public string[] arrayOfClasses { get; set; }
}
```

Controller ACtion:

```
//Had to set ValidateInput to false since one of the strings contains < (it errored without this)
[HttpPost, ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult watchClasses(IEnumerable<SelectedClassesArray> selectedClassesArray)        
    { //Breakpoint here shows that selectedClassesArray is null
        foreach (var item in selectedClassesArray)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your action is expecting a List of arrays:

```
watchClasses(IEnumerable<SelectedClassesArray> selectedClassesArray)
```

You probably want to get only the array, which is in the view model:

```
watchClasses(SelectedClassesArray selectedClassesArray)
```

And what @taxicala said makes sense, try passing only the array, not an array inside another array:

```
data: { selectedClassesArray: selected }
```

The posted property name must match the view model parameter's name.

Comment: Using `data: selected` lets me then see the property `arrayOfClasses` but it's still empty as seen here [http://imgur.com/Eg0hsiP](http://imgur.com/Eg0hsiP)

Comment: @Jrow but did you change the action params as I said ?

Comment: Yes, it's `[HttpPost, ValidateInput(false)]
        public ActionResult watchClasses(SelectedClassesArray selectedClassesArray)        
        {
            
            return View();
        }` 
now

Comment: @Jrow ok, I'm almost sure that if you use `watchClasses(string[] arrayOfClasses)` it will work. I'm afraid for using that class as parameter you would change a little you data to post.

Comment: @Jrow how it worked, with `watchClasses(string[] arrayOfClasses)` ?

Comment: Yup, changed it to `watchClasses(string[] arrayOfClasses)` and the javascript to `data: { arrayOfClasses: selected }`

Comment: Which I assume means that the ViewModel isn't being used but I'm ok with that.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/ClassSearch/watchClasses",
    // I have tried setting data both ways with the same result:
    //data: { selectedClassesArray: selected },
    data: selected,
    traditional: true,
    success: function (data) { alert("SUCCESS"); }
});
```

Or perhaps the traditional serialization is failing:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/ClassSearch/watchClasses",
    // I have tried setting data both ways with the same result:
    //data: { selectedClassesArray: selected },
    data: { selectedClassesArray: selected },
    traditional: false,
    success: function (data) { alert("SUCCESS"); }
});
```

Comment: When I use `data: { selectedClassesArray: selected}` I get this [http://imgur.com/IvaUNNp](http://imgur.com/IvaUNNp) and when I use `data: selected` I get this [http://imgur.com/Eg0hsiP](http://imgur.com/Eg0hsiP) so it seems like `data: selected` is working "better"?